# Sorting a two dimensional struct array

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, struct

I am attempting to sort a two dimensional struct array(ie. a struct array where each struct contains a struct array).  My code sorts the parent struct and the struct inside the parent correctly.  However, when the parent struct is swapped into its correct position the struct array inside it is reset to its original order.

NOTE: The student name must contain a first and last name(or the program will crash). Also the grade must be a capital "A", "B", "C", "D" or "F". I have to use a sorting algorithm that I write (i chose bubble sort). I can't use vectors or sort() functions etc.(This is homework)

```
Current Output:

Enter student name: Bob Chatter
Enter class title: Chem
Enter units for Chem: 3
Enter grade for Chem: A
Enter class title: Bio
Enter units for Bio: 3
Enter grade for Bio: B
Enter class title: Algebra
Enter units for Algebra: 4
Enter grade for Algebra: A
Enter class title:
Enter student name: Frank Brandon
Enter class title: Music
Enter units for Music: 3
Enter grade for Music: A
Enter class title:
Enter student name: Brad Anderson
Enter class title: CoSci
Enter units for CoSci: 3
Enter grade for CoSci: A
Enter class title:
Enter student name:
Student's name: Bob Chatter
Chem,A
Bio,B
Algebra,A
GPA: 3.70
Student's name: Frank Brandon
Music,A
GPA: 4.00
Student's name: Brad Anderson
CoSci,A
GPA: 4.00
Student's name: Brad Anderson
CoSci,A
GPA: 4.00
Student's name: Frank Brandon
Music,A
GPA: 4.00
Student's name: Bob Chatter
Chem,A
Bio,B
Algebra,A
GPA: 3.70
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Bob Chatters classes are not sorted, when I debug they are sorted correctly until the students are sorted by last name, at which point the sorting of the Classes reset.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;


struct Class
{
    string title; 
    int units;
    char grade;

};
struct Student
{
    string name;
    double gpa;
    Class classes[500];
};

int const SIZE = 50;
void initStudent(Student[], int);
void readStudent(Student[], int,  int&);
void gpaCalculate(Student&);
void print(Student[], int);
void stringToCharArray (string, char[]);
string returnLastName(string);
void sort_name(Student[], int);
void bubbleUpLastName(Student[],int, int);
void bubbleUpClass(Student[],int, int);
void swapStu(Student&, Student&);
void swapStusClass(Class&, Class&);


int main()
{   
    int numberOfStudents = 0;
    Student students[SIZE];
    initStudent(students, SIZE);
    readStudent(students, SIZE, numberOfStudents);

    for(int i = 0; students[i].name != "";i++)
        gpaCalculate(students[i]);
    print(students, numberOfStudents);
    sort_name(students, numberOfStudents);
    print(students, numberOfStudents);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
void initStudent(Student st[], int s)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < s; i++)
    {
        st[i].gpa = 0.0;
    }

}

void readStudent(Student st[], int s, int& nStus)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < s; i++)
    {   
        string tmpName;

        cout << "Enter student name: ";
        getline(cin, tmpName);
        if(tmpName == "")
            break;
        st[i].name = tmpName;
        nStus++;


        for(int j = 0; j < 500; j++)
        {   
            string tmpTitle;
            cout << "Enter class title: ";
            getline(cin, tmpTitle);
            if (tmpTitle == "")
                break;
            st[i].classes[j].title = tmpTitle;

            cout << "Enter units for " << st[i].classes[j].title << ": " ;
            cin >> st[i].classes[j].units;
            cout << "Enter grade for " << st[i].classes[j].title << ": " ;
            cin >> st[i].classes[j].grade;
            cin.ignore();
        }   
    }
}


void gpaCalculate (Student& s)
{
    double unitsByPoints = 0;
    double totalUnits = 0;

    for (int i = 0; s.classes[i].title != ""; i++)
    {

        int grade = 0;
        char ltrGrade = s.classes[i].grade;
        switch (ltrGrade)
        {
        case 'A':
            grade = 4;
                break;
        case 'B':
            grade = 3;
                break;
        case 'C':
            grade = 2;
                break;
        case 'D':
            grade = 1;
                break;
        case 'F':
            grade = 0;
                break;
        }
        unitsByPoints += s.classes[i].units*grade;
        totalUnits += s.classes[i].units;

    }
    s.gpa = unitsByPoints/totalUnits;
}

void print(Student st[], int size)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << "Student's name: " <<  st[i].name << endl;
        for (int j = 0; st[i].classes[j].title != ""; j++)
        {
            cout << st[i].classes[j].title << "," << st[i].classes[j].grade << endl;
        }
        cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << "GPA: " <<  st[i].gpa << endl;
    }
}

// Returns the last name of the student passed in
string returnLastName(string s) 
{
    int i = 0;
    while (s[i] != ' ')
    {
        i++;
    }
    return s.substr(i + 1, s.length() - (i + 1));
}

 //sorts the students according to name and their classes according to their title
void sort_name(Student st[], int numValues)
{
    int stuCurrent = 0;
    int numClasses = 0;
    while (stuCurrent < numValues - 1)
    {   
        int classCurrent = 0;
        for(int i = 0; st[stuCurrent].classes[i].title != ""; i++)
        {
            numClasses = i;
        }
        while (classCurrent < numClasses)
        {
            bubbleUpClass(st,classCurrent,stuCurrent);
            classCurrent++;
        }


        bubbleUpLastName(st, stuCurrent, numValues-1);

            stuCurrent++;
    }
}

// Moves the student with the last name that should be first alphabeticaly into the first position of the Student array
void bubbleUpLastName(Student st[],int startIndex, int numValues) 
{
    for (int index = numValues; index > startIndex; index--)
    {   
        if ((returnLastName(st[index-1].name).compare(returnLastName(st[index].name)) > 0))
        {
            swapStu(st[index], st[index-1]);
        }
    }
}

// Moves the Class that should be first alphabeticaly (according to title) into the first position of the Class array
void bubbleUpClass (Student st[],int startIndex, int stuIndex)
{
    int numValues = 0;
    for(int i = 0; st[stuIndex].classes[i].title != ""; i++)
        numValues = i;
    for(int index = numValues; index > startIndex; index--)
    {
        if(st[stuIndex].classes[index - 1].title.compare(st[stuIndex].classes[index].title))
        {
            swapStusClass(st[stuIndex].classes[index], (st[stuIndex].classes[index - 1]));
        }
    }
}
void swapStu(Student& s1, Student& s2)
{
    Student tmp;
    tmp = s1;
    s1 = s2;
    s2 = tmp;
}

void swapStusClass(Class& c1, Class& c2)
{
    Class tmp;
    tmp = c1;
    c1 = c2;
    c2 = tmp;
}

/*



Define a structure called Class (with uppercase C) with the following data:
title, units and grade.

Define a structure called Student with the following data:
name (full name), gpa, and classes which is an array of Class structures (all the classes the student has taken so far).

Write an initialize function that receives an array of Student structures and its size and sets the gpa of all to 0.0.

In main, create 50 Students and call the above function to initialize the gpa for all 50 Students to 0.0. 

Then, pass the array of student structures and its size to a read function that will read student data from the user and store the entered data in the array of student structures.  The user will enter student name followed by the class title, units and grade received for each class he or she has taken.  When finished entering class information for a student, the user will just press Enter (an empty string) and to end entering more students, he or she will do the same for the student name. 

Example:

Enter student name: Maria Gomez

Enter class title: English 101
Enter units for English 101: 3 
Enter grade for English 101: A

Enter class title: Math 201
Enter units for Math 201: 4
Enter grade for Math 201: B

Enter class title: [User enters RETURN to indicate no more classes]

Enter student name: Kevin Duran

Enter class title: Poly Sci 101
Enter units for Poly Sci 101: 3 
Enter grade for Poly Sci 101: A

Enter class title: Math 201
Enter units for Math 201: 4
Enter grade for Math 201: B

Enter class title: [User enters RETURN to indicate no more classes]

Enter student name: [User enters RETURN to indicate no more students]

Once all Studnets have been entered, pass each element of the array of Student structures (element by element) to a gpa function which will compute and return the gpa for each Student using the classes array within each Student structure which contains the units and grade for each class taken by the student.  Store the gpa returned by the above function in the gpa member of the Student structures.  GPA is calculated by multiplying the number of units for each class by the points received for that class, and then adding all these products together and dividing it by total number of units.  The points received for a class is based on the grade: for A, it's 4; for B, it's 3; for C, it's 2; for D it's 1; and for F it's 0.  For example, if a student has take 3 classes with 3, 4, and 3 units and has received A, B, and C for these classes, respectively, then, the GPA will be 3 x 4 + 4 x 3 + 3 x 2 / 10 = 3.0.

Print all students showing name, followed by all classes taken, the grade received and the gpa using a display function which receives the array and its size as parameters.

Then, using a sort_name function, sort the student structures based on their last names and for each student, sort the classes he or she is taking based on class title.  Display the sorted list of students using the display function by calling it from main.

For example:

Kevn Duran
Poly Sci 101, A
Math 150, B
GPA: 3.0

Maria Gomez:
English 101, A
Math 201, C
GPA: 2.9

Robert Small
Comp Science 801, C
Comp Science 802, D
GPA: 1.9

Tom Wang
Comp Science 808, A
Comp Science 839, B
GPA: 3.5

Then, sort the students based on their GPA's using a sort_gpa function and print the list again using the display function. 

Then, ask what to search for - name or gpa.  If name is selected, read a student name from the user and, using a binary search function that takes the array, its size and the name to search for, finds the student and displays all of his or her information (name, gpa, units and list of classes taken).

Example:

Enter a student name:  Robert Small

Robert Small:
Comp Science 801, C
Comp Science 802, B
GPA: 2.5

If GPA is selected, read a GPA and using another binary search find the student with the given GPA by passing the students array, its size and the GPA to search for.  Display the name of the student with the specified GPA in main.  

Example:

Enter GPA to search for:  2.5

Robert Small was found with the GPA of 2.5

If the name or GPA is not found, tell the user it was not found; e.g.: There was no student with a GPA of 2.5; or Robert Small was not found.

Then, pass the array of student atructures and the size to a stats function which will return the average of the GPA's of all students and through two reference parameters will output the student structures that have the minimum and maximum GPA's.  Print the average GPA, as well as the names of the students who have the minimum and maximum GPA in main, like so:

Average GPA = 3.17

Robert Small has the minimum GPA of 2.5.

Tom Wang has the maximum GPA of 3.5. 

Finally, read a maximum and minimum GPA from the user and pass the array of student structures and its size, as well as two other arrays of student structures of the same size to a function which will store all students with a GPA of above the minimum in the highGPA array and all those with a GPA below the maximum in the lowGPA array.  Display the students stored in these two arrays by passing them each from main to the display function.  In other words, the highlow function receives two uninitalized arrays of student structures and populates them based on the GPA criteria passed to it (minimum GPA and maximum GPA).  Then, upon return to main, main passes each of these arrays to the display function to display them.  For example, if the user enters 2.0 for the maximum GPA, the lowGPA array gets filled out with all those students who have a GPA of less than 2.0.  Likewise, if the minimum GPA is 3.5, the highlow function populates the highGPA array with those students who have a GPA of 3.5 or higher.

Example:

Enter maximum GPA:  2.0

Enter minimum GPA:  3.5

Students with a GPA of lower than 2.0:

Robert Small 1.9

Students with a GPA of 3.5 or higher:

Tom Wang 3.5

When writing the highlow function, take advantage of the fact that the array elements are sorted based on the GPA, so to find all the students with a GPA of equal to or higher than the minimum GPA, it doesn't make sense to start from the first element in the array. Instead you can start from the midpoint. If the midpoint is lower than the minimum GPA, you can increment the index until the midpoint is no longer smaller and then all the GPA's from that point on will be larger and part of the high GPA's.  For low GPA's of course, you'd want to start from the beginning of the array and compare and store each that's lower than the maximum until they are no longer lower.

Functions you must write for this assignment (in addition to main):

initialize, read, display, sort_name, sort_gpa, search-name, search_gpa, stats, highlow.

Upload your cpp and exe files using the Browse and Upload buttons below and click Finish once both have been uploaded to the site.*/
```

What is causing the struct array inside the parent struct to be reset?

Comment: What is causing the struct array inside the parent struct to be reset.

Comment: Show the simplest input which you think produces wrong output. Show the output too and the expected output of this example.

Comment: @Azzi does `Class classes[500];` declaration work? or should it be `struct Class classes[500];`

Comment: @PiotrNycz I posted the current output in my question.

Comment: @aakash Yes the declaration Class classes[500]; works since it declares an array of Class objects that are already declared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When comparing `Class::title` you forgot to add comparison to compare value:

Your line:

```
if(st[stuIndex].classes[index - 1].title.compare(st[stuIndex].classes[index].title))
```

Should be:

```
if(0 < st[stuIndex].classes[index - 1].title.compare(st[stuIndex].classes[index].title))
```

I say you forgot - because you have this explicit comparison in your function to sort students.

Now explanation of your result: at first, just by chance - the classes for some student are sorted, but after that position of your student changes (this is bubble sort) and next sorting is done on these classes - so because actually you don't sort classes, but just changes its positions, you can have their original sequence in next step.

---

As a bonus I advice not to use compare for sorting - just use `operator <`:

```
if(st[stuIndex].classes[index - 1].title < st[stuIndex].classes[index].title)
```

much simpler, isn't it?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've been looking for something a lot more complicated.  Also one of my while statements was off :)